# Serial Ports - There is an error in XML document (5, 3870)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, serial-port, xml-serialization

Here I have a class I've created for the purpose of sending text-files and images over a serial port:

```
 public class SendItem
{
    private byte[] bytes;
    private string _fileName;
    private string _extension;
    private int bytesSin;

    public string Extension
    {
        get { return _extension; }
        set { _extension = value; }
    }

    public string FileName
    {
        get { return _fileName; }
        set { _fileName = value; }
    }

    public byte[] Bytes
    {
        get { return bytes; }
        set { bytes = value; }
    }

    public SendItem()
    {


    }

    public void SendFile(SerialPort serialPort1)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            OpenFileDialog OFDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            OFDialog.Title = "Open File";
            OFDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)" + "|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            OFDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";

            bool? userClickedOK = OFDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (userClickedOK == true)
            {
                serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();
                string chosenFile = OFDialog.FileName;
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(OFDialog.FileName);
                _extension = ext;

                byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(chosenFile);
                SendItem newSendItem = new SendItem();
                newSendItem._extension = ext;
                newSendItem._fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(chosenFile);
                newSendItem.bytes = data;
                byte[] view = newSendItem.Serialize();
                string test = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
                serialPort1.Write(newSendItem.Serialize(), 0, newSendItem.Serialize().Length);
                //serialPort1.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("File: {0}{1}",_fileName, _extension);
    }
}
```

There is quite a few redundant things in the SendFile method, but I ask that it would be ignored in favour of the following issue I keep on having.

Whenever I send a text file or just plain chat text from a textbox, the following block of code is executed without triggering the catch:

```
void _sPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

        byte[] data = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
        string message = string.Empty;

        sp.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        try
        {
            SendItem receivedObject = data.Deserialize<SendItem>();
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\" + receivedObject.FileName + receivedObject.Extension, receivedObject.Bytes);
            message = "File has been recieved.";
            sp.Write("File sent.");
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            errors = exp.Message;
            message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
        }
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => _response.Add("Friend: " + message)));
    }
```

The problem comes in when I try to send an image... It trigger the catch and gives the exception There is an error in XML document (5, 3870).

My serializer and deserializer I've written is as follow:

```
public static byte[] Serialize<T>(this T source)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.Serialize(stream, source);
        byte[] buffer = stream.GetBuffer();
        stream.Close();
        return buffer;
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(this byte[] source)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(source);
        T result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

Can anyone point out where I'm making my mistake?  I've been debugging it for ages and I can't wrap my head around it.

**EDIT:
I am also including the serialised data for an image I tried to send, after looking at it, it appears my Byte might be too big for the serial port - is there any way to adjust this or allow the serial port to take all of the data sent over?

> 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

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may or may not be the *whole* problem, but this is definitely *a* problem:

```
byte[] buffer = stream.GetBuffer();
```

That's quite possibly returning more data than you want - because it's not limiting itself to the length of the stream. `MemoryStream` has the handy `MemoryStream.ToArray` method to simplify this:

```
public static byte[] Serialize<T>(this T source)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.Serialize(stream, source);
    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

(There's no benefit from closing a `MemoryStream` that you've created like this - and if you *did* feel you needed to, you should use a `using` statement.)

Likewise your `Deserialize` method can be simplified to:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(this byte[] source)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T) serializer.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(source));
}
```

Given that you were effectively trying to deserialize "the XML document - and then probably a load of "blank" data, that may well be the issue.

EDIT: Now there's a second problem:

```
byte[] data = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
string message = string.Empty;

sp.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```

You're assuming that *all* of the data is ready to read in a single go. That won't be true if there's more data than the buffer size of the serial port. Instead, if you're trying to put multiple "messages" onto what is effectively a stream, you'll need to *either* indicate the end of a message (and keep reading until you find that) or write the length of the message before the message itself - then when reading, read that length and then make sure you read that many bytes.

This is a standard issue when you try to use a stream-oriented protocol as a message-oriented protocol.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment!  I've added the changes and I think the image when converted into text to send over the serial port might just be too much data to send in one go. I am stumped on how to fix it though.

Comment: @user3897321: If you can use it as a stream, it should be fine - but I've just seen that your reading code is broken too. Will edit for that.

Answer (score -2):

You should use `ToByteArray()` instead of `GetBuffer()`.